# Hive connection problem with Kafka using docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hive

We've working now on a project in which we must store the metadata from a kafka topic in hive using docker.

We've worked with various docker-compose file variations but we still had the problem in term of connecting the Kafka topic with hive.

After further investigations, we found that we need hive version 3 but we don't know how to put docker-compose file together.

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:1.1.0-hadoop2.8-java8
    container_name: namenode
    volumes:
      - namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - ./infra/zeppelin/examples:/opt/sansa-examples
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
      - "8020:8020"
      - "8081:8081"

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:1.1.0-hadoop2.8-java8
    container_name: datanode
    volumes:
      - datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    links:
      - namenode

  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:2.1.0-hadoop2.8-hive-java8
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8090:800"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
      - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=localhost
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    links:
      - namenode
      - datanode

  spark-worker:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.1.0-hadoop2.8-hive-java8
    container_name: spark-worker
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
      - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=localhost
    links:
      - spark-master

  hue:
    image: bde2020/hdfs-filebrowser:3.11
    container_name: hue
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    environment:
      - NAMENODE_HOST=namenode
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
    links:
      - spark-master

  zeppelin:
    image: bde2020/zeppelin:0.0.1-zeppelin-0.7.1-hadoop-2.8.0-spark-2.1.0
    container_name: zeppelin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./data:/opt/zeppelin/data
  #    - ./infra/zeppelin/conf:/opt/zeppelin/conf
      - ./infra/zeppelin/logs:/opt/zeppelin/logs
      - ./infra/zeppelin/notebooks:/opt/zeppelin/notebook
      - ./infra/zeppelin/examples:/opt/sansa-examples
    environment:
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: "hdfs://namenode:8020"
      SPARK_MASTER: "spark://spark-master:7077"
      MASTER: "spark://spark-master:7077"
      SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS: "--jars /opt/sansa-examples/jars/sansa-examples-spark.jar --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
    links:
      - spark-master

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive
    container_name: hive-server
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      - "HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL=jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
    links:
      - namenode
      - hive-metastore
    ports:
      - 10000:10000

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    links:
      - namenode
      - hive-metastore-postgresql
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    ports:
      - 9083:9083

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    links:
      - zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper  
      
  # kafka:
  #   image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
  #   container_name: kafka
  #   ports:
  #     - 9092:9092
  #   environment:
  #     KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  #     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
  #     KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
  #     KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  #     KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  #     KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
  #   volumes:
  #     - kafka:/var/lib/kafka
  #   links:
  #     - zookeeper
  #   depends_on:
  #     - zookeeper

  nifi:
    image: xemuliam/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - 5080:5080
      - 5443:8443
      - 5081:5081
## for scaling we have to do this
#      - 8080
    links:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./infra/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/conf
      - ./infra/nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/logs
      - ./data:/opt/datafiles
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/flowfile_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/database_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/content_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/provenance_repository
    environment:
      ZK_NODES_LIST: zookeeper
      IS_CLUSTER_NODE: 1
      ELECTION_TIME: 1 min

volumes:
  namenode:
  datanode:
  zookeeper:
  kafka:
  nifi:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want different version of Hive, you need to replace `image: bde2020/hive`.

Or, you should use Spark Structured Streaming or Nifi to consume Kafka and write to **HDFS** rather than use Hive Kafka Storage Handler. Then you wouldn't need any specific version of Hive.

You could also use HDFS Sink for Kafka Connect, which also has Hive integration.

Hive server itself doesn't "store" anything.

Also, the Confluent container is defined correctly for being able to access from other containers, and the wurstmeister one is not